# Nested git repositories without submodules?

Tags: git

It seems a git repo inside a parent repo isn't included in a commit on the parent unless it's setup as a submodule. Is it possible to override this behaviour and treat the nested git repo as any other directory? I don't want to rely on external dependencies through submodules but want to use git to manage these dependencies within the project.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to "mange dependencies", but I propose two ways to achieve what you want, plus some precisions about the nature of submodules in Git.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a subtree merge. That will leave you with a single repository and a single history.

Comment: Are you sure that **a git repo inside a parent repo isn't included in a commit on the parent unless it's setup as a submodule**? Because that's what I want, and if you're right, then Git has that out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1/ You could override that through:

- either a [git config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES) setting: set the environment variable `$GIT_DIR`
  you define your `.git` directory of the nested Git working tree as an **external** `.git` (external to both the nested repo and the main repo)
- or by setting your nested repo 'N' **outside** the main repo, but checkout that repo 'N' *inside* the main repo:

```
core.worktree
```

Set the path to the root of the work tree. This can be overridden by the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable and the `--work-tree` command line option

In both case, the idea is to have a nested worktree without any `.git` subdirectory in it.

2/ With submodules, the nested git repo is not really included in the parent repo.
A [**special entry**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297899/checkout-past-git-submodule-commit/2300638#2300638) is made in the parent tree to record the external Git SHA1.

```
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..4c4c5a2
```

See also "[nature of Git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)" (third part of the answer)

---

Nine years later, [this discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/20191031202015.u5l3wzvn64zypnad@camp.crustytoothpaste.net/) is quite clear:

> > I don't want to use submodules or crutches
> >     such as renaming all `.git/` in subdirectories.
> >     I just want that Git treats my `.git/` subdirs as plain dirs with any other names.

**Brian m. Carlson** ([`bk2204`](https://github.com/bk2204)) answers:

> This is not possible.
>   You can't add a non-bare repository as a part of a parent repository without using submodules.
>   Git uses the `.git` directory to find the working tree and for safety reasons doesn't allow files or directories named that to be checked in.
>   Allowing users to check in `.git` directories would allow configuration and hooks to be stored as part of the repository, which would allow the execution of arbitrary code if someone cloned it and then changed into the
>   subrepository.

Comment: Your methods 1a and 1b are perfect for me, thank you. I'm sure this isn't the recommended approach but I really need this flexibility. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: So no option to make git treat nested .git directories as plain directories ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D not that I know of

Answer (score 8):

I found another method that seems to work for me

If you `git add somefolder/` <-- make sure you have the `/` on the end, Then it will add all the files instead of treating it like a submodule.

More is mentioned here: http://debuggable.com/posts/git-fake-submodules:4b563ee4-f3cc-4061-967e-0e48cbdd56cb

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I get an error message if I try to add the nested .git itself: 
`error: Invalid path 'test/data/fixtures/clean/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
error: unable to add test/data/fixtures/clean/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG to index
fatal: adding files failed` It does seem to work with the actual files though, thanks, it's a start

Comment: I've seen where people rename a nested `.git` folder to `.checkout_git` https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2015/go-in-a-monorepo/
And rename it back as as needed

Comment: This no longer seems to work, git warned about adding a nested git repository and  tried to add it like a submodule for me.

Comment: This seemed to work for me still (Jan 2021)

Answer (score 2):

See also [Are git submodules the only safe way to have working copies within working copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918768/are-git-submodules-the-only-safe-way-to-have-working-copies-within-working-copies) .

Actually, when I came across the current discussion, I was concerned with a problem different from the on solved here: using git as a kind of archiving tool that could archive a filesystem tree which already has some git working directories... perhaps the other question is closer to my problem.

Comment: Here is a tool targeted at my problem: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ffr9y2l0jh4J:eigenclass.org/hiki/gibak-backup-system-introduction+nested+git&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ru . There are probably other similar tools.

Comment: oops - broken link in the comment (which you probably should delete and add to your answer)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it's worth mentioning.

If you zip up the folder containing the repository you can check that into the outer repository.

This can be helpful because you'll have the full complete state including `git reflog`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple (and dirty) thing you can do is renaming the `.git` folder

I had this folder structure:

```
|- .git
|- folders
|- second-repo
     |- .git
     |- folders
```

I simply used this bash command from root folder:

```
mv /.git /.not_git
```

Now you can go inside the `second-repo` and use its own git for commands and in this way you can go back and forth to use both git repos.

> PS: Git subomodules is the correct way to handle this but in my case I
>   couldn't go for them