# Whitelist directories with .gitignore

Tags: git, whitelist, subdirectory

I want to have two directories in one git repository.
My method of choice is to create a git repository in a top-level directory and then use .gitignore to whitelist the two directories of interest.
Requirements are within the comments of my attempted .gitignore file:

```
# Blacklist everything
*
# Whitelist directories of interest and their contents
# stage files in directory A/ recursively
!A/
!A/*
# stage files in directory B/B1/ recursively (without staging files in B/)
!B/B1/
!B/B1/**
# Whitelist files of interest
# stage only the .md files (not .txt files)
!*.md
```

How to write a .gitignore file that whitelists two directories?

The above gitignore file is based on [.gitignore ignoring whitelisted folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003448/gitignore-ignoring-whitelisted-folder)

Here is the directory I tested .gitignore on:

```
$ find A B C
A
A/a.md
A/a.txt
A/A1
A/A1/a1.md
A/A1/a1.txt
B
B/b.md
B/b.txt
B/B1
B/B1/b1.md
B/B1/b1.txt
C
C/c.md
```

Here is how I tested the .gitignore file:

```
$ find A B C            #list all paths
$ git init
                        #test .gitignore:
$ git add . --dry-run   #show what would be staged
                        #edit gitignore and test again
```

Expected output:

```
$ git add . --dry-run
add 'A/A1/a1.md
add 'A/a.md
add 'B/B1/b1.md
```

Answer (score 3):

This .gitignore file whiteslists the directories A and B/B1, and excludes .txt files:

```
#exclude files and directories in top directory
/*

#include the A directory
!/A

#include the B directory
!/B
#exclude files and directories in B
/B/*
#include the B/B1 directory
!/B/B1

#ignore .txt files
*.txt
```

It is based on last example in http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with several .gitignore files:

```
# .gitignore
*
!.gitignore
!A/
!A/*
!B/
!B/*
!*.md

# A/.gitignore
!*

# B/.gitignore
!*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, based on the information in the cross-referenced question and the directory setup in this question:

```
$ mkdir junk
$ cd junk
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jleffler/soq/junk/.git/
$ mkdir -p A/A1 B/B1 C
$ > A.md
$ > A/a.md
$ > A/a.txt
$ > A/A1/a1.md
$ > A/A1/a1.txt
$ > B/b.md
$ > B/b.txt
$ > B/B1/b1.md
$ > B/B1/b1.txt
$ > C/c.md
$ cat > .gitignore
*
!A/
!A/**
!B/
!B/**
!*.md
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    A.md
    A/
    B/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)   
$ git add A.md A B
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   A.md
    new file:   A/A1/a1.md
    new file:   A/A1/a1.txt
    new file:   A/a.md
    new file:   A/a.txt
    new file:   B/B1/b1.md
    new file:   B/B1/b1.txt
    new file:   B/b.md
    new file:   B/b.txt

$
```

After adding `A` and `B`, all the files within are waiting to be added.  Note that the `.gitignore` file contains the directories (the trailing slash is not mandatory, AFAICT), and then the names `!A/**`.  The double star is key to the recursive search.

---

I used `git reset` (having never actually made a commit), and jiggered with `.gitignore`.  I'm not clear that the goals are self-consistent at the moment.  However, this modified `.gitignore` file:

```
*
!A/
#!A/**.md
!B
!B/B1
#!B/B1/**.md
!*.md
B/b.md
```

plus `git add A.md A B` yields:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   A.md
    new file:   A/a.md
    new file:   B/B1/b1.md

$
```

You should be able to play with variations on the themes shown to get the result you desire.  The `!*.md` line tracks all `.md` files.  The `B/b.md` line ignores `B/b.md`, of course.  The `.md` file in `C` is ignored because C is blacklisted (via the `*`).

Comment: Jonathan, sorry I didn't make the requirements more explicit.
Your .gitingnore comes close, but there are two short comings:
1) It is staging B/b.md; is there a way to only stage the directories A/ and B/B1/ (without staging the files in B/)?
2) It is staging .txt files; is there a way to stage only the .md files?

Comment: I'll investigate.  Please update the question to make these points clear there, too.  Do you want `B/b.md` included because it is a `.md` file or excluded because it is in `B`?

Comment: "stage only the .md files (not .txt files)" is global.