# How can I exclude everything but all top-level dot files and a subdirectory?

Tags: git, gitignore

In keeping track of my essential configuration files with Git, I'm having trouble writing my .gitignore file.

My goal is to include two things in my repository:

1. All dotfiles in my user directory `~/`, which is my gitroot.
2. the hidden folder `~/.vim/bundle`

So far, I have tried the following approach, to no avail.

.gitignore:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Include top-level dot files.
!/.*

# Include vim plugins
!/.vim/bundle/*
```

This only stages the dotfiles in my gitroot.

**Note.**

My gitroot is my user directory `~/`.

**Update**

In the following form, the `~/.vim`  folder *is* staged:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Include top-level dot files.
!/.*

# Include vim plugins
!/.vim
```

So, I'm guessing that I should express the pathname `/.vim/bundle` differently, somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You're running into an optimization that breaks your use case: once Git decides not to look inside a directory, it never finds the files *within* that directory that it would add.  To fix it you need at least one more rule:

```
!/.vim/bundle/
```

You can use a different rule to defeat all optimization:

```
!*/
```

which should also make the problem go away (at the expense of much deeper searches which result in a lot of slowness).

#### Long

You have a good start, but you have run into a problematic optimization (that the Git folks are, I think, trying to fix).  We must also make assumptions about what is currently in your *index* (aka staging-area) as the index contents affect how Git scans through directories.  Let's assume that your index is truly empty, as it would be right after `git init`-ing a new repository.  That way, since there are no existing index entries, they cannot affect Git's normal directory-scanning process.

Let's suppose your work-tree here has files named `README` and `.profile`, and directories `d/` and `.vim/`.  Your `.gitignore` has three rules.  The first one is a positive rule ("do ignore") and the second and third are negated rules ("don't ignore").  The rules themselves, minus the `!`, are:

```
*
/.*
/.vim/bundle/*
```

Now when Git is working on `README` it first checks `*`, which matches, then `/.*`, which does not match, then `/.vim/bundle/*` which also does not match.  The last matching rule takes effect: that's `*` which says "do ignore" so `README` will be ignored.  The file `.profile`, on the other hand, the first two rules, so the second one applies, and it says `!` so `.profile` is untracked but not ignored: `git status` will whine about it, and `git add .` will add it to the index.

Now let's consider how `d/` and `.vim/` are handled.  These are directories, not files: Git is not going to save them, but it may or may not save files that are *within* them.  To do so, it will have to read and check all the file names within them.  This is pretty expensive, so Git will first try to *skip* the directory entirely.  This is the problematic optimization I mentioned.

Anyway, `d/` matches the first rule but not the other two.  This means Git gets to *skip reading `d/` entirely*.  `git status` will not whine about it and `git add` will not scan it.

We're all good so far.  `.vim/` matches the second rule (but not the third) so Git will look inside `.vim`.

Let's say that `.vim/` contains `.netrwhist`, `after/`, `bundle/`, and maybe some other directories.  `.netrwhist` matches `*`, does not match `/.*`, and does not match `/.vim/bundle/*`, so the `*` match applies and it gets ignored.  The `after/` directory matches `*`, does not match `/.*`, and does not match `/.vim/bundle/*`, so it goes unread.

Now we hit the problem: `.vim/bundle/` is a directory.  Git checks this path name against your `.gitignore` directives.  `bundle/` matches `*`.  `.vim/bundle` does not match `/.*` as that means *files in the top level*; `.vim/bundle/` is a directory and is not in the top level.  The path also does not match the third directive `/.vim/bundle/*`, which requires that this be a file or directory *within* `.vim/bundle/`.  So **the only matching directive is the first one, and `.vim/bundle` goes unread** just like `d/` did.

This means that Git never finds any of the files or directories *within* `.vim/bundle/`.  It never checks the files (if any) against anything and it never scans the subdirectories for more files.  You need to force Git to look inside `.vim/bundle/`.

#### An entry in the index changes a lot

If there is some file in the index whose path name is `.vim/bundle/a/b`, Git is going to have to scan the directory `.vim/bundle/a`.  So any *new* files placed in there will show up!  I'm not sure if Git ever skips `.vim/bundle/` itself in this case (in theory it could but I don't think it does in practice).  Once you have a file path in the index, that file is *tracked* and its presence in any `.gitignore` becomes irrelevant.

Note, however, that files that are in the index *now* are not necessarily in the index *tomorrow*, if you remove them or if you check out some other commit where those files are not present.  The whole thing is a little bit tricky.

Comment: Why doesn't `.netrwhist` match `/.*`? Is it because it is not located in the top-level gitroot directory, but a subdirectory? The same question for `/after`, it residing in a *subdirectory*.

Comment: Right: `.netrwhist` is `.vim/.netrwhist` and the matching code is a little squirrelly around directories vs files when there is a `/` in both sets of paths. It would match `/.*/.*` or `/.*/*` for instance. You can also use `**` between or before/after `/`, to mean "zero or more directories". Use `git check-ignore -v` to test whether some name(s) match some pattern(s). I suspect there might also be some minor differences in some Git variants (Git 1.7.x is still in use on CentOS!).

Comment: Okay! I just read it in the two sentences afterwards. :) You explained it in the next paragraph.

Comment: So you're saying there is no whitelisting approach to including a specific subdirectory? That is, one which is independent of the presence of files in the index?

Comment: Moreover, I don't recall adding any files from the `~/.vim/bundle` directory directly. The `.gitignore` file in my answer managed to add the files in the `/bundle` directory nonetheless. How can this be?

Comment: Sure, you can list the directory—that's what you did in your own answer. It's the same general idea: start by skipping over everything, then don't-skip `/.vim` and then `/.vim/bundle`, which you can spell with or without a trailing `/` at that point. Your un-anchored `.*/` ignore directive will then ignore `/.vim/bundle/.foo/` if it exists. `/.vim/*` will only skip files-and-directories directly in `/.vim` since it's anchored there.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying that this procedure is index dependent. Hence, if I were to start from scratch, initiating the directory with `git init`, it wouldn't work because of the empty index. As I understand it, the procedure in my answer worked by luck; certain files were apparently present in the index, according to your answer.

Comment: No, that's not the idea: the tricky part with the index is that index content can *force* the scan of a directory, even if an earlier `.gitignore` might have skipped it. In other words, you can have `.gitignore`s that hide files from `git status` *sometimes*, but not *always*, depending on index content. This makes it difficult to describe the optimization-based problem: sometimes Git *doesn't* optimize!

Answer (score 3):

The leading slash indicates an absolute path relative to gitroot; remove it to select all dotfiles.

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Include all dot files.
!.*

# Include vim plugins
!/.vim/bundle/*
```

[Here is](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore) a handy and concise reference with examples.

You will need to stage and then commit `.gitignore` for the changes to take effect. Happily you can repeatedly `git commit --amend` with further changes to keep the history clean until you have what you want.

As a vaguely-related aside, I've often seen people attempt to match "a folder of name `folder` anywhere in the project" with `/folder`, where it ought to be `**/folder`.

Comment: My gitroot is `~/`. Furthermore, the leading forward slash doesn't seem to make a difference in selecting all dotfiles. At the moment, it ignores the subdirectory.

Comment: Perhaps silly question: have you _committed_ the updated `.gitignore`, or just modified, or just staged it?

Comment: I just staged it. So, you're saying it doesn't go into effect until after a commit?

Comment: @MusséRedi That's correct. You need to commit the file for changes to take effect (pitfall of the ambiguity in "make git aware"). Happily you can just continue to `git commit --amend` with further changes to keep the history clean until you have what you want.

Comment: `git status` seems to notice changes in a saved `.gitignore` file immediatly, without having to first commit  the `.gitignore` file. Moreover, the `.gitignore` at hand only stages the top-level dotfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240475/3646263) to write the following adequate `.gitignore` file. :)

```
# We use a whitelisting approach to track certain configuration files.
# Apparently, this needs to be done recursively because git can't see past a directory that is not
# included. Hence, if we want to include a subdirectory, we first need to include its upper
# directory, by the whitelisting procedure as shown below.

# Exclude all files and non-hidden directories.
/*

# Include all dotfiles.
!.*

# Exclude all hidden directories.
.*/

# Include the upper directory.
!/.vim

# Exclude all files and non-hidden directories.
/.vim/*

# Include the vim plugins.
!/.vim/bundle
```