# .gitignore ignores .github folder even though it's explicitly included

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a `.gitignore` which uses a global exclusion pattern to ignore any unwanted files. It looks like this:

```
#"git-include" pattern
*.*
*/**

!.github/**
!src/**

!.gitignore
!.dockerignore
!README.md
```

Despite this, I'm still seeing my .github folder be ignored.

```
$> git ls-files -ci --exclude-from=.gitignore
.github/workflows/main.yml
```

I'd really prefer my .gitignore to match what is actually cached. I'm wondering if this has something to do with the ".git" prefix, though that sounds kind of strange and I can't find anything after a quick look at the documentation.

I've tried various .gitignore configurations that would try to include the .github directory. e.g.:

```
!*github/**
!.github/workflow/*
!.github/workflow/main.yml
```

None of these would unignore the files.

I tried changing from `*/**` to `/*/**` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003448/gitignore-ignoring-whitelisted-folder) but that didn't work.

I did manually include the file using `git add .github/** -f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug gitignore issues, use `git check-ignore -v <path>`. For example :

```
$ git check-ignore -v .github
.gitignore:2:*.*    .github   # <- .github is matched by this pattern
```

---

When a directory is matched by a gitignore pattern, git will not enter that directory to check whether some files should be included.

In your situation:

- `.github` is ignored by a patten (`*.*`),
- no pattern is present to "counter" this ignore rule,

so `.github/**` has no chance to apply.

You need to add a rule to explicitly unignore that directory:

```
!.github/    # <- add this
!.github/**  # <- now this has a chance to apply
```

---

A blind shot at trying to simplify your gitignore:

```
# ignore everything, but only at the root level of your repo:
/*

# unignore these specific files and directories:
!.gitignore
!.dockerignore
!README.md

!.github/
!src/

# since the first ignore rule will not apply at nested levels, you don't
# have to deal with a mess of '/**' rules
# side bonus: 'git status' and 'git add' should be quicker :)
```