# Error after removing submodule: The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm getting this error after I've removed a submodule. The path in question is not in my .gitignore file, nor is there anything relevant in my .git/info/exclude file. I don't have a .gitignore_global file. Why is git trying to ignore this path and how can I fix this?

```
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
MyTest/MyTest/lib/submodules/ScreenRecorder
Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

This is the command I'm trying to execute:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/ScreenRecorder.git MyTest/MyTest/lib/submodules/ScreenRecorder
```

This is being executed from my git repos root directory.

Comment: It would be a good idea to actually _post_ the path which is ignored and where it exactly lies under your directory structure.

Comment: @akluth just added that info

Comment: Thanks. What exact commands are you executing when getting this error?

Comment: @akluth added that info as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the relevant `[submodule]` stanza in my `.git/config` solved the issue for me.

My guess that the superrepo will automatically ignore all files in submodules since they are not tracked. Therefore, if there is a stray `[submodule]` stanza in your config, git will add the path as an ignore pattern.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in "[Git is ignoring files that aren't in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27615009/6309)"

> Another reason for receiving this error message from Git is when executing the `git submodule add` command while a previous `git` command has crashed and left the lock file
>   (this can happen, for instance, when you use custom scripts which include `git` commands and you haven't noted the crash).

In that case, an error message like "`The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files`" is not very expressive.

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), said error message generation is improved for "[`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) ".

See [commit c816385](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c81638541cbbf5868e79037ca29b6e37e47461e5) (08 Jan 2020) by [Kyle Meyer (`kyleam`)](https://github.com/kyleam).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 25794d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25794d6ce9f34ed5dedc569c5050afdb04518744), 05 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodule add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c81638541cbbf5868e79037ca29b6e37e47461e5): show 'add `--dry-run`' stderr when aborting
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kyle Meyer</sup>
>
> Unless `--force` is specified, '`submodule add`' checks if the destination path is ignored by calling '`git add --dry-run --ignore-missing`', and, if that call fails, aborts with a custom "`path is ignored`" message (a slight variant of what '`git add`' shows).
>
> Aborting early rather than letting the downstream '`git add`' call fail is done so that the command exits before cloning into the destination path.
>
> However, in rare cases where the dry-run call fails for a reason other than the path being ignored --- for example, due to a preexisting `index.lock` file --- **displaying the "`ignored path`" error message hides the real source of the failure**.
>
> Instead of displaying the tailored "`ignored path`" message, let's report the standard error from the dry run to give the caller more accurate information about failures that are not due to an ignored path.
>
> For the ignored path case, this leads to the following change in the error message:
>
> ```
> The following [-path is-]{+paths are+} ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
> <destination path>
> Use -f if you really want to add [-it.-]{+them.+}
> ```
>
> The new phrasing is a bit awkward, because '`submodule add`' is only dealing with one destination path.
>
> Alternatively, we could continue to use the tailored message when the exit code is 1 (the expected status for a failure due to an ignored path) and relay the standard error for all other non-zero exits.
>
> That, however, risks hiding the message of unrelated failures that share an exit code of 1, so it doesn't seem worth doing just to avoid a clunkier, but still clear, error message.

So you will get a more explicit `fatal:...` error message mentioning the `index.lock`, instead of an "`ignored path`"

Answer (score 2):

I've found that Git for Windows will also throw this error if you are trying to add a local folder, and use Windows-style backslashes instead of Linux-style forward-slashes for the path.

For example, the following command will complain that the path is ignored in .gitignore (even if you don't have a .gitignore file):

```
git submodule add C:\mysubmodule\
```

The solution is to change to forward-slashes:

```
git submodule add C:/mysubmodule/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the existing `.gitignore` file and create a new one worked for me.