# Git submodule is ignored

Tags: git-submodules, gitignore

When I try to add a submodule via

```
git submodule add git@domian:repo.git contact
```

I get the following message:

> The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>
> contact
>
> Use -f if you really want to add it.

Here is my `.gitignore`:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files:
!*.py
!*.md
!*.gitignore
!.gitmodules
!contact/
```

It is resolved by using the suggested `-f` option, but I am curious why the `!contact/` entry in `.gitignore` does not alleviate the problem.

Comment: Is this to dumb of a question that nobody even comments on, let alone answers it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submodule is composed of a [gitlink (a special entry 160000 in the Git repository index)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#Documentation/git-fast-import.txt-Inlinedataformat), and a remote URL+path in the .gitmodules.

So excluding `!contact/` would still ignore the gitlink "`contact`" (which is not a folder `contact/`, but a special "*file*")

This would work better, and allow the `git submodule add` to proceed:

```
!contact
```

And if any other cause would still block the `git submodule add`, the [next Git 2.26 (Q1 2020) will provide a more helpful error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100146/6309).

Answer (score 0):

I don't hit that error in your particular case (I have git version 2.21.0.windows.1).

I do hit that error when trying to add a submodule outside the parent repository, though (which apparently isn't supported):

```
$ git submodule add https://github.com/user/repo ../repo
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
../repo
Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

Best guess is it's a bug...so adding `!contact/` to your `.gitignore` doesn't fix it because it's not actually the `.gitignore` causing the problem.

What git version do you have? You can download the [source code for your particular version](https://github.com/git/git/releases), search for the error message (e.g. [here it is](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh#L237) in v2.21), and trace through the code to figure out what actually goes wrong.