# How to add a Git submodule on a subdirectory that is excluded in .gitignore?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
my-project
├── modules
│   ├── my-first-module
│   ├── my-second-module
│   └── my-fourth-module
```

I included the *modules* directory in my *.gitignore* file and made an exception for *my-third-module*:

```
/my-project/modules/*
!/my-project/modules/my-third-module/
```

Then when I execute `git submodule add git@git.my-app/my-third-module.git` from *my-project/modules/* path, I get:

```
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
my-project/modules/my-third-module
Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

It seems the exclusion of `/my-project/modules/my-third-module/` in *.gitignore* is not taken into account.

So, I tried to create an empty *my-third-module* directory but in this case the `git submodule add` command complains:

```
'my-third-module' already exists and is not a valid git repo
```

Apparently `git submodule add` requires that the directory doesn't exists, so it's not the way to go.

Why the exclusion of *my-third-module* is not taken into account by Git?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100146/1941316):

> Unless `--force` is specified, `submodule add` checks if the destination path is ignored by calling `git add --dry-run --ignore-missing`

So, I executed `git add --dry-run --ignore-missing my-third-module` and I got:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
my-project/modules/my-third-module
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

That made me suspect that there was probably an issue with excluding in *.gitignore* a directory that doesn't exist.

After I created manually *my-third-module*, I executed again the `git add` command and now it's OK.
That means Git needs the directory to be created to be able to exclude it. But since it's created it's well excluded.
The command `git submodule add` simply doesn't take charge of this automatically.

Therefore it's safe using `-f` in this case to add the submodule:

```
git submodule add -f git@git.my-app/my-third-module.git
```

The *my-third-module* directory will be well excluded from being ignored by Git after its creation.