# Netbeans and Git, .obj files ignored

Tags: git, github, gitignore, netbeans-8

I am working on a small git project involving .obj files.

When I look at the "project tab" I see they are ignored

[image]

But I cant understand why, if I look at my .gitignore:

```
/DepthPeeling/nbproject/private/
/DepthPeeling/dist/
/DepthPeeling/build/
```

It looks fine

If I open a Git Bash and type

```
$ git add dragon.obj
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
DepthPelling/sry/depthPeeling/data/dragon.ogj
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no file added
```

Wut?

Might it be there is more than one .gitignore file? If I look for them, I find only the one in the root directory of the project itself (the one I shown before) and nothing more..

Edit: so it looks like I have a global ignore D:\Documents\gitignore_global.txt

```
#ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.dll
*.lib
*.sbr
```

Comment: Yes, there can be a `.gitignore` in each directory, *and* [ignored files can be specified in other ways](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Try `find <repo> -name .gitignore` and `cat <repo>/info/exclude`.

Comment: Can you do a search for other `.gitignore` files in your project?  From your screen capture, it looks like you are running Windows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just used the window explorer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily find which `.gitignore` (and which rule) is responsible for ignoring your `.obj` file using [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- dragon.obj
```

The OP reports:

```
"D:\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt":5:*.obj –
```

That is similar [to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703637/6309):

> it was the installation of [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview) (a tool visualize git repo) which un-logically created under documents folder a `gitignore_global.txt` which included plenty of exclusions.

A `git config -l` should show something similar to:

```
[core] 
   excludesfile = C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
```

Comment: Oh god, you were right, "D:\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt":5:*.obj

Comment: @elect Looks like a source tree installation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436405/git-is-ignoring-files-that-arent-in-gitignore#comment42848910_18703637. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Anyway the commit see them now and I am uploading them right now, thanks!