# Gitignore is ignoring a directory I want to track

Tags: git

I am trying to switch to the mode where I exclude everything in line 1 of .gitignore and then include the files I really want to track.  Here is my .gitignore file:

```
*
!*.py
!README.md
!vizing.pdf
!Data*
```

I can add the folder Data, but I really want Data and all it subfolders.  When I try to add a subfolder, this happens:

```
> git add Data/EdgeColoring
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Data/EdgeColoring
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

I tried the suggestions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436405/git-is-ignoring-files-that-arent-in-gitignore), but they didn't help much.

```
> git check-ignore -v Data/EdgeColoring
.gitignore:1:*  Data/EdgeColoring
```

I can't find another .gitignore file with a * pattern, so it seems that Data* doesn't match Data/EdgeColoring.  Why is this?  What is the right pattern?

Comment: Git's ignore system works best if you only ignore what you want to ignore. Is there a reason you're trying to do things the other way?

Comment: Use the prefix `!` to unignore a pattern that was previously ignored by a general rule.

Comment: It's just the way my mind works.

Answer (score 0):

Doing as git suggested in its response to you, I added the `-f` flag:

```
amber:IgnoreTest pjs$ touch Data/EdgeColoring/foo
amber:IgnoreTest pjs$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
amber:IgnoreTest pjs$ git add Data/EdgeColoring
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Data/EdgeColoring
Use -f if you really want to add them.
amber:IgnoreTest pjs$ git add -f Data/EdgeColoring
amber:IgnoreTest pjs$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   Data/EdgeColoring/foo

amber:IgnoreTest pjs$
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the -f too.  I'd like to have git track all the files in Data/ and it subfolders automatically, though.