# .gitignore is ignoring files in a directory

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file which I am trying to only let git see the dirs and files in /wp-content/plugins/event-manager and /wp-content/themes/StringsV2.

The one for the theme is working but the plugin one only includes the dir and ignores all the files.

```
# Ignore everything in the root except the "wp-content" directory.
/*
!.gitignore
!wp-content/
!wp-config.php

# Ignore everything in the "wp-content" directory, except the "plugins"
# and "themes" directories.
wp-content/*
!wp-content/plugins/
!wp-content/themes/

# Ignore everything in the "plugins" directory, except the plugins you
# specify (see the commented-out examples for hints on how to do this.)
wp-content/plugins/*
!wp-content/plugins/event-manager/

# Ignore everything in the "themes" directory, except the themes you
# specify (see the commented-out example for a hint on how to do this.)
wp-content/themes/*
!wp-content/themes/StringsV2/
```

Any ideas where it is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Git won't include dirs unless they have files in them...Have you done `git add wp-content/plugins/event-manager/`? That should track the directory and expose its inner contents to git.

Comment: Yes I have tried adding but still nothing it doesn't track the files

Comment: What makes you think that your files are not being included? Please edit your question, and give us the output of `git status`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the git check-ignore to find out how git is ignoring a file/folder for example:

```
$ git check-ignore -v sql
```

found from this article: [Git is ignoring files that aren't in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436405/git-is-ignoring-files-that-arent-in-gitignore)