# Git ignore files which I do not want it to

Tags: git

I have a directory named "Build" (from Carthage) which appears to be ignored by Git. I really do not want it to. I tried to add one file in the directory individually, it said:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
platforms/ios/Carthage/Build/iOS/Zip.framework/Zip
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

But I checked my .gitignore it does not seem to do have such a rule.

What exactly has happened?

EDIT:

This is my gitignore:

```
*.swp
tags
.DS_Store
*.xcuserstate
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
*.espressostorage
Makefile
```

Comment: Can you paste your gitignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git is ignoring files that aren't in gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436405/git-is-ignoring-files-that-arent-in-gitignore)

Comment: Oh I think it's from another .gitignore in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 3 ignore files on git:

- $HOME/.config/git/ignore
- $GIT_DIR/info/exclude
- .gitignore

You can check what file is ignoring your file:

```
git check-ignore --verbose platforms/ios/Carthage/Build/iOS/Zip.framework/Zip
```

Then you delete the rule.

Comment: Thanks, helpful. Want to add that there can be multiple .gitignore in any of the sub-directories all working together.