# How do you add .gitignore to staging when using git add --all

Tags: git

When using git add --all, .gitignore does not get added to staging.  So then I try to manually add .gitignore like this

```
$ git add .gitignore
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.gitignore
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

So I have to use -f to force add .gitignore which is annoying

Comment: Well, you could choose to not gitignore the `.gitignore` file as an alternative...

Comment: Possibly also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9436505/4280359.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `.gitignore` entry from the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: .gitignore isn't in the .gitignore.  Just Pods/ for an iOS project

Comment: @MichaelL `.gitignore` is in some `.gitignore` file. You can run `git check-ignore -v .gitignore` in order to see which `.gitignore` file ignores that `.gitignore` file.