# git ignore some files but its not in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have local git repository and there are a .gitignore and .gitattributes files in the directory.
my .svg files are being ignored by git but its not in the .gitignore file

this is my .gitignore file

```
# CakePHP specific files #
##########################
/config/app.php
/config/.env
/logs/*
/tmp/*
/vendor/*

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db

# Tool specific files #
#######################
# vim
*~
*.swp
*.swo
# sublime text & textmate
*.sublime-*
*.stTheme.cache
*.tmlanguage.cache
*.tmPreferences.cache
# Eclipse
.settings/*
# JetBrains, aka PHPStorm, IntelliJ IDEA
.idea/*
# NetBeans
nbproject/*
# Visual Studio Code
.vscode
# Sass preprocessor
.sass-cache/
.phpstorm.meta.php/*
.github
```

i used this command to show me the ignoed files
`git status --ignored` 
and this is the result:

```
.github/
.idea/
.phpstorm.meta.php/
codealike.json
config/app.php
logs/
plugins/AdminView/
plugins/MetronicAdminView/
plugins/SiteView/webroot.zip
tmp/
vendor/
```

the folder plugins is where the .svg files are

but when I used  `git check-ignore **/ -v` to see where I ignored this the folder plugin doesn't show at all

```
.gitignore:5:/logs/*    logs/
.gitignore:6:/tmp/*     tmp/
.gitignore:7:/vendor/*  vendor/
```

how can I find where the problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git is ignoring files that aren't in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436405/git-is-ignoring-files-that-arent-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
it's because of the

```
Icon?
```

in the CakePHP `.gitigore` that ignored the `.svg` files

and something that I found was that you should write the exact path for `git check-ignore -v` to work properly

so when I run  `git check-ignore -v plugins` i receive nothing

but when run

```
git check-ignore -v plugins/AdminView/webroot/img/icons/logout.svg
```

I received this response

```
.gitignore:16:Icon?     plugins/AdminView/webroot/img/icons/logout.svg
```

hope this helps