# Install Atlassian Stash on Openshift

Tags: openshift, bitbucket-server

Is it possible to install Atlassian Stash on Openshift? I suppose I should start from the DIY cartridge, but I have no idea on how to set up everything git-related or if it is possible to use Openshift for non-HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should be possible to install Atlassian Stash in OpenShift, however I an not sure  that it buy's you much benefit. As you will be limited on disk space (so you will not be able to create many git repositories, or allow them to get too big).

You may also run into issue with nesting of git repositories. I think [Nested git repositories without submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317652/nested-git-repositories-without-submodules) explains more on this.

However you should be able to install stash in the Tomcat container as it should just be a simple war file, it is the atlassian-stash directory from download that you get (note its exploded).

Note that OpenShift also provides you a git repository, and Atlassian provides hosting of Stash (which is better suited for what I think you are looking for).

Comment: So do you think I simply have to deploy the `war` file? Isn't there some kind of git runtime needed?