# Can't get rid of git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I added some Haml templates to my Rails 3 project with

```
git clone git://github.com/psynix/rails3_haml_scaffold_generator.git lib/generators/haml
```

only to find, when I tried to edit some of those files, that this was a submodule, so I couldn't commit changes that I made within the `lib/generators/haml` directory. Now every time I `git status`, I get

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   lib/generators/haml
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

but `git add lib/generators/haml` has no effect. I really just want to have the files, not a submodule, but I'm finding the submodule impossible to get rid of:

```
> git rm --cached lib/generators/haml
rm 'lib/generators/haml'
> git status

# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    lib/generators/haml
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   lib/generators/

> git commit -m "Removed submodule"

[master 02ae4c7] Removed submodule
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 160000 lib/generators/haml

> git status

# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   lib/generators/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

> git add lib/generators/haml
> git status

# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   lib/generators/haml
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   lib/generators/haml

> git commit -m "Re-added lib/generators/haml"

[master c966912] Re-added lib/generators/haml
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 160000 lib/generators/haml

> git status

# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   lib/generators/haml
```

Additional `git add`s are useless. If I try `git rm -rf lib/generators/haml`, I get

```
fatal: git rm: 'lib/generators/haml': Operation not permitted
```

It just won't die! I've looked up [how to delete submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759587/un-submodule-a-git-submodule), but in this case, there is no `.submodules` file, nor is there any mention of the submodule in `.git/config`. Yet if I run `git submodule update`, I get

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'lib/generators/haml'
```

I deleted the directory, but I get the same results! What's going on? Do I need to create a `.gitmodules` file just to delete the submodule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is no submodule, is it possible it (i.e. '`haml`') is actually *not* a submodule?

```
git clone git://github.com/psynix/rails3_haml_scaffold_generator.git lib/generators/haml
```

means: create `lib/generators/haml` directory, and checkout in it the master branch of `git://github.com/psynix/rails3_haml_scaffold_generator.git`.

The fact that you can do a `git status` not from the root of your new repo ( `lib/generators/haml`), but three levels above (where `lib` is) means you have clone a repo within a repo.

Both repo can work independently, but you should add  `lib/generators/haml` to the `.gitignore` of the parent repo (like in hits [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918768/are-git-submodules-the-only-safe-way-to-have-working-copies-within-working-copies)).

Comment: but this won't push the new files into the repo, FYI

Comment: my issue turned out to be unrelated, but this helped.

Answer (score 6):

The submodule is shown in git status as modified if it has untracked files.  If you invoke `git diff lib/generators/haml`, you'll most likeyl see something like this:

```
diff --git a/lib/generators/haml b/lib/generators/haml
index 3019fec..653c59a 160000
--- a/lib/generators/haml
+++ b/lib/generators/haml
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 653c59ad72925c9ccbde67e8e484e15d4b6dd25d
+Subproject commit 653c59ad72925c9ccbde67e8e484e15d4b6dd25d-dirty
```

This means that inside this submodule are some untracked files left.  They can't be added through commands in the parent project; instead you should traverse into the sumbodule and add them (or add entries to `.gitignore`)... Or you can just ignore the status message.

The latest git version (1.7.1, I think) shows this information in status:

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   lib/generators/haml (untracked content)
```

Comment: OK, I think I understand: I should go into `lib/generators/haml` and then do git stuff from there whenever I change something in there.

As you suggested, I updated my git from 1.7.0.5 to 1.7.2, and that does give me the more useful message.

It still blows my mind that git thought there was a submodule even after I blew away `lib/generators/haml`along with its `.git` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used:

```
git add lib/generators/haml/
```

to add the files in the submodule to the HEAD and remove the submodule. But then again it might not work because you don't really have a submodule.

Note that there is a trailing slash after the path. If you put this git removes the submodule and puts it into the HEAD, unlike:

```
git add lib/generators/haml
```

which will just change the commit to be checked out from the submodule in git submodules.