# Orchard repository synch

Tags: git, orchardcms

My team is relatively new to the Git and we are developing a new website using Orchard CMS.  We have in premise Git server where we would like to keep all the custom modules. But at the same time the source code should be synched with latest versions of Orchard CMS releases.  So we have two repositories to synch. The orchard repository on codeplex for the framework updates and other for the custom modules being developed. If it is possible, can anyone suggest me the best approach we have to take to achieve this? Any help on this greatly appreciated.

-George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend to create a fork of Orchard sources -- because you might need to make changes to Orchard core (which you might offer for inclusion into main Orchard source repo via pull request, if your changes turn to be valuable for everyone).

Then you create a separate repository for your module inside the main Orchard source tree:

```
OrchardRootFolder
    .git
    src
        Orchard.Web
            Modules
                YourModule
                    .git
```

People often recommend using git submodules for nested repositories:

[Git repository in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980960/git-repository-in-a-git-repository)

But in your case the repositories are not connected strongly, so it is better to keep them independent, and just add your project subfolder to ignore list in the root Orchard repository. See the following topic for details:

[Are git submodules the only safe way to have working copies within working copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918768/are-git-submodules-the-only-safe-way-to-have-working-copies-within-working-copie)